# how to group by on outer references or any alternative way?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am passing in two dates and need to group by the results by these two dates, but cannot do it as I get the error

> Msg 164, Level 15, State 1, Line 24 Each GROUP BY expression must
>   contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

the query is as follows:

```
declare @sd datetime ='2012-07-01 00:00:00.000' ,
        @ed datetime ='2012-09-30 00:00:00.000' ;

select @sd,@ed, 
        count(i.id)as count,
        sum(case when oi.rating <50 then 1 else 0 end) as unfav,
        sum(case when oi.Rating =50  then 1 else 0 end) as neu,
        sum(case when oi.Rating >50  then 1 else 0 end) as fav,
        avg(oi.Rating)as 'Av Rating'
        from Items i (nolock)
        inner join ItemOrganisations oi (nolock) on i.ID= oi.ItemID
        inner join Lookup_ItemTypes it (nolock) on it.ID = i.ItemTypeID

        inner join Batches b (nolock) on b.ID=i.BatchID
        inner join Lookup_ItemStatus lis (nolock) on lis.ID = i.StatusID
        inner join Lookup_BatchStatus lbs (nolock) on lbs.ID = b.StatusID
        inner join Lookup_BatchTypes bt on bt.id = b.Typeid

        where lbs.Name = 'Completed by Analyst' or lbs.Name='Delivered/Imported into Neptune Online'
        and lis.Name = 'Complete'
        and i.IsRelevant = 1
        and bt.Name = 'Live'
        group by @sd,@ed
        having i.OverrideDate between @sd and @ed
```

If I do not group by this is the result I get which is wrong:

```
2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 2011-01-31 00:00:00.000 1   0   0   1   55
2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 2011-01-31 00:00:00.000 7   1   0   1   50
2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 2011-01-31 00:00:00.000 7   1   0   0   20
2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 2011-01-31 00:00:00.000 1   0   0   0   NULL
2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 2011-01-31 00:00:00.000 8   1   0   6   66
2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 2011-01-31 00:00:00.000 1   1   0   0   10
2011-02-01 00:00:00.000 2011-02-28 00:00:00.000 1   0   0   1   55
2011-02-01 00:00:00.000 2011-02-28 00:00:00.000 7   1   0   1   50
2011-02-01 00:00:00.000 2011-02-28 00:00:00.000 7   1   0   0   20
2011-02-01 00:00:00.000 2011-02-28 00:00:00.000 1   0   0   0   NULL
2011-02-01 00:00:00.000 2011-02-28 00:00:00.000 8   1   0   6   66
2011-02-01 00:00:00.000 2011-02-28 00:00:00.000 1   1   0   0   10
2011-03-01 00:00:00.000 2011-03-31 00:00:00.000 1   0   0   1   55
2011-03-01 00:00:00.000 2011-03-31 00:00:00.000 7   1   0   1   50
2011-03-01 00:00:00.000 2011-03-31 00:00:00.000 7   1   0   0   20
2011-03-01 00:00:00.000 2011-03-31 00:00:00.000 1   0   0   0   NULL
2011-03-01 00:00:00.000 2011-03-31 00:00:00.000 8   1   0   6   66
2011-03-01 00:00:00.000 2011-03-31 00:00:00.000 1   1   0   0   10
2011-04-01 00:00:00.000 2011-04-30 00:00:00.000 1   0   0   1   55
2011-04-01 00:00:00.000 2011-04-30 00:00:00.000 7   1   0   1   50
2011-04-01 00:00:00.000 2011-04-30 00:00:00.000 7   1   0   0   20
```

Comment: There is no reason for doing this, please explain what result you expect and what is your logic for grouping the results

Comment: Are you sure these results from same query? how do you get different results for `@sd,@ed` in first two columns?

Comment: this query is being run for each row retrieved from a temp table. that table contains rows of sd and ed columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query, as written, is trying to group by a constant expression.  I think you can just change the last two lines to:

```
and i.OverrideDate between @sd and @ed
```

The `group by` statement is unnecessary.  You are only returning one row, so all rows will be aggregated.

If you needed to include the `group by` for some reason (such as this being automatically generated code), then you can use a trick such as:

```
group by (case when OverrideDate  = OverrideDate  then @sd end),
         (case when OverrideDate = OverrideDate then @ed end)
```

But I'm guessing that is unncessary in this case.

Comment: +1 for the *case when* trick that I did not know :) (but it looks useless here)

Comment: Im still getting the outer reference error when using the case statement.

Comment: @xerxes . . . Actually, I think you need to have a variable reference in it, now that I look at the code where I actually use it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you using `group by` *and* `having` clauses here at all. I think you could simplify your where clause as;

```
where lbs.Name in ('Completed by Analyst',
                   'Delivered/Imported into Neptune Online') 
      and lis.Name = 'Complete'
      and bt.Name = 'Live'
      and i.IsRelevant = 1
      and i.OverrideDate between @sd and @ed
```